# How to get current user's profile information in YouTube Data API v3

Tags: youtube-api

In V2 you could hit the `/api/users/default` path to get infomation such as the user's username. This is documented here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_profiles

In our migration to V3 I also need to be able to pull the users username, but can't find any documentation showing how to do so. Is this functionality replicated in V3, or is there another way to accomplish this task?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In v3, user info is basically channel info.
By doing a channels->list "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list", you will get the information under 'snippet.channelId' "https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.channelId"

Comment: Also, there's a human-readable display name under channel.snippet.title

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! Would be great If there was a little more documentation indicating this is how it should be done as there was for v2.

Comment: How are unlinked accounts treated? see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14988876/230167

Comment: Foudn this answer, but neither channels->list nor channel->snippet->title exist another. Where would this information have moved too?

Comment: Unlinked accounts are edge cases for v3, there won't be many going forward.

Comment: This will not work if the user does not have any channels

Answer (score 5):

Youtube API v3 does not support user information any more. Use userinfo API.

set scope: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`
(a space between scopes)

and get: `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token={access_token}`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, as user profile for me meant the google account profile, not the channels associated with them.

Comment: Thank you! This works great. You can get the ID, name, given_name, picture and locale with that request. Do you know of any other URLs to call to get the information on the User's Youtube account? Maybe something like number of videos on account, etc.?