# How to get the old username field with Youtube Data API V3

Tags: ruby, youtube-api

As noted in a similar question ([How to get current user's profile information in YouTube Data API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961246/how-to-get-current-users-profile-information-in-youtube-data-api-v3)) there can be a difference between a youtube user's username (found at youtube.com/user/{the username}) and their channel title. The channel title can be retrieved through the channel/list resource, however that channel title may not be equal to the username that owns that channel. The problem here is that where the username is unique, the channel title may not be and this causes great confusion inside our app (as we have no way of differentiating between user accounts).

Is there any way in the V3 Data API to get the username?

Answer (score -1):

There's a human-readable display name under [channel.snippet.title](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels#snippet.title)

Comment: Yeah we're currently using this field. The problem is that say I have 2 youtube accounts (Work and Personal) and I'm using the API for both of them. While they have unique channel id's, they both have the same value unter `channel.snippet.title`, my name. The old names were unique, so they allowed the user to differentiate between account, however now there is no human readable way to tell which account is which. This is why we need to grab the old username.

Comment: For example this page (http://www.youtube.com/user/AimInteractive) has the old username in it, AimInteractive. However when you go to that page, the channel name is Salman Khan, something entirely different. The api response for this would by Salman Khan, however what I really want is AimInteractive

Comment: There's no way to get the legacy username for a channel using v3 of the Data API. If you're interested in differentiating between two channels that have the same channel.snippet.title, then I'd recommend showing both that value and the channel.snippet.thumbnails.default.url image in your UI. If you have two channels with the same profile image and title, then... you might want to reconsider that :-)

Comment: @JeffPosnick Your suggestion to deal with fake accounts is... don't, smiley face?