# Which url for getting json data for youtube uploaded videos from a user on api 3.0

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I need just some explanations on youtube apis.

In the version 2.0 urls like these are used to grab information about profiles, but now version 2.0 is deprecated

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/[USERNAME]/uploads?alt=json&v=2&orderby=published&max-results=50
```

At the moment I'm using this behaviour to grab data, but the last json request is forbidden.

//search of channel of user

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername={USERNAME}&key={API_KEY}
```

//search videos of channel

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&maxResults=50&channelId={CHANNEL}&key={API_KEY}
```

//search videos

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id%2Csnippet%2CcontentDetails%2CfileDetails%2CliveStreamingDetails%2Cplayer%2CprocessingDetails%2CrecordingDetails%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus%2Csuggestions%2CtopicDetails&id={VIDEO_LIST}&key={API_KEY}
```

So is there are way to grab same data from one url for YouTube api version 3.0, having parameters like **USERNAME** and **API_KEY** ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get current user's profile information in YouTube Data API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961246/how-to-get-current-users-profile-information-in-youtube-data-api-v3)

Comment: it's not a duplicated, because the one you linked is about USER information, i need to retrieve USER'S UPLOADED VIDEOS with all info like ratings, duration, id, link ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the way to grab the last 50 (maximum allowed) videos of a user with Youtube with Api 3.0

//search channels of user

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername={USERNAME}&key={KEY}
```

//search playlist items of upload channel

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId={PLAYLIST}&key={KEY}
```

//search videos of the playlist items of the upload channel

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id,snippet,contentDetails,status&id=BBfPP0rTjxo,o04cSB5afGc&maxResults=50&key={KEY}
```

Answer (score 1):

Version 3 of the YouTube Data API can be found here:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&forUsername={USERNAME}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError


DEVELOPER_KEY = "your key"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(search_item):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

    search_response  = {}
    search_results = []
    search_response = youtube.search().list(
        q=search_item,
        type="video",
        part="id,snippet",
        maxResults=50
        ).execute()
    search_results.append(search_response)
    if search_response.has_key('pageInfo'):
        if search_response['pageInfo'].has_key('totalResults'):
            totalResults = search_response['pageInfo']['totalResults']
            for i in range(len(range(50,totalResults,50))):
                if search_response.has_key('nextPageToken'):
                    pT = search_response['nextPageToken']
                    search_response = {}
                    search_response = youtube.search().list(
                    q=search_item,
                    type="video",
                    part="id,snippet",
                    pageToken = pT,
                    maxResults=50,
                    ).execute()
                    print "ok"

                    time.sleep(1)
                    search_results.append(search_response)
    for i in search_results:
        for j in i['items']:
            statistics = search_video(j['id']['videoId'])
            j['statistics']=statistics
    return search_results

def search_video(id):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
    data = youtube.videos().list(
        id=id,
        part="statistics"
        ).execute()

    return data['items'][0]['statistics']
def main():
    #call the youtube_search function by passing the usernameof the user in youtube
    #eg
    #data = youtube_search('Google')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Use this code for getting json data for youtube uploaded videos from a user on api 3.0 .
You will get maximum 500 videos per user.
The api key will be available https://console.developers.google.com/