# Get GCP account from YouTube server key

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a server API key for YouTube which I've been using for over 3 years, and it does not appear anywhere in my GCP project. It is still active in my app.
It's possible that it was created with a different account and I can't remember or figure out which one. Is there anything I can do to retrieve the account which owns this key?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to [Retrieve information about a channel](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/channels#channels-list). `Whereas the v2 API provided a way for retrieving a user's profile, the v3 API provides a method for retrieving information about a channel`. Take note that in V3, user information also referred as channel information in youtube api. See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961246/how-to-get-current-users-profile-information-in-youtube-data-api-v3).

Comment: but I don't have OAuth2.0, only an API key (example: https://content.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=Ks-_Mh1QhMc&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics&key=AIza################-##################)